# Probability of packages

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose mail is delivered 6 days each week. Someone sent you ten packages, all of which are scheduled to arrive this week. But you don't know what day any of the packages will arrive. What is the expected number of packages that you receive on a particular weekday?

Comment: Are the packages equally-likely to arrive on any of the 6 days?

Comment: I think they are independent of each other

Comment: I tried to give you a general answer. Let me know if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the packages arrive at random, i.e., if any of the packages is equally-likely to arrive any of the 6 days then any package has a probability $P=1/6$ of arriving any given day. This means that , for $X$ =number of packages arriving per day, we have: $$E(X)=\frac{1}{6}(1)+\frac{1}{6}(2)+...+\frac{1}{6}(10)=\frac {1}{6}=(55/6)=8+1/6 $$ packages.

If the packages do not arrive randomly, then we must have a distribution function that tells us the probability of package #k ; $k=1,2,..,10$  arriving in day j $; j=1,2,..6.$ , we do a sum of a similar form as above, but substituting $\frac{1}{6}$ for $P_{kj}$ , i.e., the probability of pacage #k arriving in day j, for all pairs $(k,j)$

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear!

Comment: Glad you liked it, SSS.